# Bulge-Disk decomposition in galaxies

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

I'm starting a new project on dark matter astrophysics in which I have to extract from some data (I will write some below) the surface brightness, to later construct the mass density profiles of de bulge-disk decomposition. Can anyone recommend me a good, base-solid and specific book/articles on how to achieve this?

Basically, I have the data of:

R(kpc)--Velocity(km/s)--Velocity Dispersion----Intensity of NII----Intensity of H$\alpha$

I've been reading a lot and nobody talks about how to compute it. Actually: [Kent S. M., 1986, A J 91,1301](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986AJ.....91.1301K) uses a method but it is not based on specific formulas, just took some data from somewhere and does the decomposition.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you have just 5 numbers per galaxy, or more? That is, do you have velocities, intensities, etc. as a function of radius?

Comment: @ChrisWhite You can't fit a bulge+disk with those data at a single radius, so I would hope it's a table as a function of R...

Comment: [This software](http://www.astro.uvic.ca/~simard/GIM2D/)/its documentation may be of interest. There's no source code, but the package is publicly available and there is some documentation. Best of luck...

Comment: Yes dear @ChrisWhite, for every galaxy, I have this table with the dependence on the galactic radius.

Comment: NB: knowing that there is a forum dedicated to astronomy & astrophysics http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ , when should we treat astrophysics question here or not ?